# Mastocytoma vs Mastocytosis?

Tags: statistics, infant, contributing-factors, mastocytoma

My 8-month old son has a mastocytoma developing on his arm (confirmed by his pediatrician). Does this mean he also has mastocytosis? Or are they two separate things?

If they are separate, how correlated are they? Anybody know of any statistics as to how likely an infant with a single mastocytoma is to developing mastocytosis later on in life?

Comment: Hi, Manny, and welcome to the site. Did you do any research on either? Can you briefly share it with us; that gives us an idea on how to build the answer.

Comment: Thanks @anongoodnurse (+1) - yes the best information I was able to find relating to mastocytoma in kids was from [MastoKids.org](http://www.mastokids.org/articles/pedmasto.php), however, they don't seem to address the one questio I'm posing here (the relationship/correlation between the two).